# How do I install Matplotlib 3.4.1 in Anaconda?

Tags: python, matplotlib, installation, anaconda, package

I want to use a package only available in version 3.4.1. When I do `conda list` then I see my matplotlib version is 3.2.2.

I've tried `conda.install matplotlib=3.4.1` but that return a `PackagesNotFound Error` across these channels:

```
Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
```

I tried `conda install --channel "conda-forge" matplotlib` to get around that, but no luck. It says all packages are already installed. I don't understand why this doesn't work as the webpage https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/matplotlib indicates that the package is v3.4.1

Edit:
I tried `conda update matplotlib` which updated mine to 3.3.4 but not 3.4.1...
After looking at this documentation: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#
I tried using `pip install matplotlib` but that just specified a bunch of `Requirement already specified: (...)` statements with no upgrade to the installation

Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you try using `pip`?

Comment: Yes, post edited just now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to the Matplotlib official site discourse and found this post: https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/matplotlib-announce-ann-matplotlib-3-4-1/21991

Using `pip install matplotlib==3.4.1` worked! Originally I had tried `pip install matplotlib=3.4.1` but using only a single "=" is wrong.

Comment: I am still getting '''pip install matplotlib==3.4.1 --user'''  '''ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib==3.4.1'''

Answer (score 3):

I tried with DavidD003 solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66932922/11753330
and it worked also with conda command:
`conda install -c conda-forge matplotlib==3.4.2`

In this way the update succeded.
Before:

```
matplotlib                3.3.4            py38hecd8cb5_0  
matplotlib-base           3.3.4            py38h8b3ea08_0
```

After:

```
matplotlib                3.4.2            py38h50d1736_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.4.2            py38h6152e83_0    conda-forge
```